# NSNumber's copy is not allocating new memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am implementing a copyWithZone method for a custom A class, in which a NSNumber pointer was declared as (retain) property

```
@class A <NSCopying>
{
  NSNumber *num;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *num; // synthesized in .m file

-(id) copyWithZone:(NSZone*) zone {

   A *new = [[A alloc] init];
   new.num = [num copy];
   return new;
}
```

When I debug, I always find new.num is the same address as the self.num.

Even if I use

```
new.num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [num floatValue]];
```

I still get the same address. In the end, I have to use

```
new.num = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:[num floatValue]] autorelease]
```

to achieve the result I want. I am just wondering why NSNumber complies to  but does not return a new memory address when copied?

Thanks

Leo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NSNumber is immutable.  Making a copy is pointless and, thus, the frameworks just return self when copy is invoked.

If a class implements NSCopying, you should mark the property as `copy` (not `retain`).  `-copy` on immutable classes (`NSString`) will simply return a reference to the object (w/a bumped retain count).  If passed a mutable instance, it'll be copied to an immutable instance.  This prevents an external party from changing the state behind your object's back.

Comment: But what about NSString, it's not mutable as well.

Comment: As Abizem says in the other answer, NSNumber is a flyweight. If you create a whole bunch of separate instances of [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], they'll generally share the same underlying storage for both the BOOL and the NSNumber object that boxes it. If you create a whole bunch of separate instances of [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"YES"], they'll generally have their own separate storage for both the characters and the NSString object that boxes them. The actual details are a little more complicated (and not part of the public interface), but that's the basic idea.

Comment: And on Lion, it is a flyweight for about 2^56 worth of values... in fact, there isn't even a singleton;  no allocation at all to represent the data.

Answer (score 10):

Not only is NSNumber immutable - for low values it as also a [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

`NSNumber` isn't mutable, so there is no need to force physical copying.

Comment: NSString isn't mutable as well, but why it could be applied with copy?

Comment: @tom: Because of `NSMutableString` making mutability possible. There is no equivalent `NSMutableNumber` so there is no need for concern.

Answer (score -2):

You should be using [[A alloc] initWithZone:zone] when implementing the NSCopying protocol.

As others have stated though, NSNumber is immutable and so returns the same object.

Comment: Zones are all but deprecated.  It doesn't matter.

Comment: Whilst NSCopying requires the following method...-(id) copyWithZone:(NSZone*) zone, initWithZone:zone IS what you should be doing. This didn't require a downvote by any stretch of the imagination!

Comment: `initWithZone:` doesn't exist. You mean `allocWithZone:`